# Cart array $_SESSION['cart'] not prininting cart items properly

Tags: php, arrays, session, cart, shopping-cart

I am doing shopping cart functionality on an ecommerce site via $_SESSION.
I added cart items successfully on every click in $_SESSION['cart'] array. but unable to print it correctly.
I made an associative array which is being a problem to handle correctly.
I dont know how to show cart items properly, tried merge array += $item or anything but nothing is working.

Here is my code ..

```
//add  item to cart 
<?php 

 session_start();
 
 if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
  $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
 }

 $item = array("pid"=>$_POST['pid'], "name"=> "bloom flowers");

 array_push($_SESSION['cart'],$item);
 echo "Done!";
 ?>

//displaying cart items

<?php include 'navbar.php';
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $value){
     echo '<h5>'.$value.'</h5>';
     }
 }

// print_r($_SESSION['cart']);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

For your case, if you want to display the data of say "name" , please use
$value['name']

Hence, change the block

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $value){
     echo '<h5>'.$value.'</h5>';
     }
```

to

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $value){
     echo '<h5>'.$value['name'].'</h5>';
     }
```

**Do the same for pid** if you want.

Hence, the whole code (fully working) is :

```
<?php 

session_start();
 
 if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
 $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
 }

 $item = array("pid"=>'1', "name"=> "Mary");

 array_push($_SESSION['cart'],$item);

foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $value){
     echo '<h5>'.$value['name'].'</h5>';
     }

 ?>
```

Comment: this code is also giving me an error

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string , this one error

Comment: Please check this testing link: [link](http://www.createchhk.com/SO/testSO_4Nov2021.php) (No error at all). **Try reloading it** and you will see the shopping cart increase by one each time with the value "Mary"